# Close windows application Form if a specific window has been closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my application to close when a specific form has been closed.

I have tried using this code below but this does not close the application, this code is on the form that I want to close the application if it is closed.

```
private void ContactListView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form fc = Application.OpenForms["ContactListView"];
    if (fc == null)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

On `Program.cs` this is not the page that opens the application and I cannot change the program so that it is.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new LogInView());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add event handler for `Form`'s [`Closed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed(v=vs.110).aspx) event like this

```
Form fc = Application.OpenForms["ContactListView"];

fc.Closed += (o, form) => { Application.Exit(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to close the application when form `ContactListView`closes than all you need to do is put some code in the FormClose event of that form.

```
private void ContactListView_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```